# What does the None in model.summary after the ___ mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I run model.summary() in keras, I get:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
output (Dense)               (1, 1)                    1         
=================================================================
Total params: 1
Trainable params: 1
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

What does the None in the bottom mean?

I ran:

```
input_numpy_array=np.array([1])
model = keras.models.Sequential()
input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_numpy_array.shape, name='input', batch_size=1)
model.add(input_layer)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False, name='output', batch_size=1)
model.add(output_layer)
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.summary()` doesn't need a `print` statement: it prints by itself, and so it returns `None`. When you print `model.summary()`, you print `None`.

```
x = model.summary()

x == None
```

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!